# Google Sheets Macro - Add Pause between Functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Macro that is activated by a button in my Sheets. It does exactly what I want it to do separated, but when I tried to combine both functions (Autofill & Sort), it doesn't finish the sort. My guess is that it is doing it all simultaneously so it's sorting before the autofill calculation is actually completed/displayed. Any way to adjust this macro so it does the Autofill and then the Sort?

```
function Sorting() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('N3:Q3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('N3:Q'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3:Q').activate()
  .sort({column: 17, ascending: false});
};
```

Comment: Try placing a SpreadsheetApp.flush() between the autofill and the sort and don't use indeterminate ranges like 'A3:Q'. Add the sh.getLastRow() to it.  Google Apps Script tends to generate many nulls with ranges like that. Personally I would never use activate in that type of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Cooper provided the solution. Below is the final code. I'm sure that it could be optimized as per his suggestions, but I'm just not familiar enough with this programming language to be able to make those changes.

```
function Sorting() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('N3:Q3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('N3:Q'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('N3:Q').activate();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3:Q').activate()
  .sort({column: 17, ascending: false});
};
```